# android linearlayout push button

Tags: android

hi i have 2 items into a linearlayout and I need to push them at screen the bottom. Now they start at too of screen. How can i do it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:src="@drawable/splash" />

<include
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:id="@+id/footer_raw"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    layout="@layout/footer_raw" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `LinearLayout` with `RelativeLayout` and give  `android:layout_alignParentBottom`="true" to your `footer_raw`

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` to your parent layout.

Answer (score 0):

change you code to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical">


<ImageView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:src="@drawable/splash" />

<include
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:id="@+id/footer_raw"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:layout_height="30dp"
layout="@layout/footer_raw" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

apply this attribute to your items,
android:layout_gravity="bottom". or use relative layout as your parent layout.